# What would be the memory consumption difference if we use non-async instead of async for asp.net/web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

As far as I know, CLR has to create a new thread when the thread pool's threads are blocked. Each thread takes approximately 1mb on the memory. Let's say server gets 10K request per second. What would be the cost of not using async in this case in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: How much time is needed for serving one request on average?

Comment: Request eventually will make 1-2 db call. let's say 50-150ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR does not create new threads whenever all the thread pool threads are blocked.  It grows the thread pool "reluctantly", and within bounds.

See

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the thread pool creates and
> destroys worker threads in order to optimize throughput, which is
> defined as the number of tasks that complete per unit of time. Too few
> threads might not make optimal use of available resources, whereas too
> many threads could increase resource contention.

[The managed thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool)

> Is there any benefits using async in terms of memory consumption?

Perhaps.  If you have a lot of concurrent requests that are waiting on back-end resources, async allows you to handle those with fewer threads.  And fewer threads means less memory for thread stacks.  However the concurrent requests *themselves* consume memory. So if the thread pool reduces the number of concurrent requests it can also reduce the amount of memory used.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is there any benefits using async in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: Yep, the thread pool queues can absorb a lot of pending work before the thread pool decides to scale-up. When you find yourself fiddling with thread pool parameters to "make it faster", you could probably do with a redesign. I hear that `async` is pretty good for this kind of thing :)

Answer (score 2):

10,000 requests per second * 0,1 seconds per request = 1,000 requests served concurrently on average.

By not using async, each request will employ one thread from the `ThreadPool`, so around 1,000 threads will by eventually¹ created by the `ThreadPool` to accommodate the demand. So the answer to your question, which is the cost of no-using async, and assuming that the number of threads in the async case would be small enough to be negligible, is 1,000 x 1MB = **1GB of extra memory**.

¹ <sub>or immediately, if you configure the number of threads that are created without delay upon demand, by using the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method.</sub>